# Hashmap not returning value as expected when retrieving using key

Tags: java, hashmap

Should be simple enough but it's driving me nuts!

Have a HashMap with a Key:Value pair as Long:Dto respectively.

When I debug, I can see the one entry in the Hashmap with a Long value as the key - but when I try a get() using the Key, I'm getting a null back.

For the following:

```
Map<Long, Dto> response = getMap();

System.out.println("Contents of HashMap: " + response);
System.out.println("Size of HashMap: " + response.size());
System.out.println("HashMap Keyset: " + response.keySet());
System.out.println("HashMap Contains: " + response.containsKey(19999984L));
System.out.println("HashMap Object: " + response.get(19999984L));
```

I'm getting the following output:

```
Contents of HashMap: {19999984={productOptionId=19999984, amount={amount=20.99, currency=EUR}, pricingType=MSRP}}
Size of HashMap: 1
HashMap Keyset: [19999984]
HashMap Contains: false
HashMap Object: null
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated here... this should work surely!

Maybe I'm missing something obvious.

Answer: So it seems my key value is of String type - as below:

```
System.out.println("Contents of HashMap: " + response);
System.out.println("Size of HashMap: " + response.size());
System.out.println("HashMap Keyset: " + response.keySet());
System.out.println("HashMap Contains: " + response.containsKey("19999984"));
System.out.println("HashMap Object: " + response.get("19999984"));
System.out.println("HashMap Class: " + response.getClass());
```

Comment: My guess is that you used `19999984` for the key rather than `19999984L` when adding to the `Map`.

Comment: Can you also add `System.out.println(response.getClass())`? maybe this is some IdentityHashMap?

Comment: You could also print type of key `response.keySet().iterator().next().getClass()` maybe you added key as Integer by using some raw types or casting?

Comment: what does the `getMap()` return? It should return Map with correct generic parameters.

Comment: @GotoFinal - you could be onto something. It's returning a String as the keySet type strangely enough. Would have thought defining the Map<Long, Dto> would have been a bit more fussy with regards the key being a String.

Comment: @Archit - the getMap() is indicated on the "Contents of HashMap:" logger statement above

Comment: @Basq, the reason for asking the question is if `getMap()` returns `Map<Long, Dto>` and uses correct generic params within its implementation too, then String/Integer etc can never come as key in Map.
 If somewhere unchecked Map is being assigned to a checked Map this happens AFAIK. An Unchecked cast warning is also generated by compiler in this case.

Answer (score 3):

Your key in the hashmap is a int type and your contains method has 19999984L which is long type.

```
Contents of HashMap: {19999984={productOptionId=19999984, amount={amount=20.99, currency=EUR}, pricingType=MSRP}}
Size of HashMap: 1
System.out.println("HashMap Contains: " + response.containsKey(19999984L));
```

That's the reason for false.

Comment: Yeah, it's actually a String bizarrely.. but got to the bottom of it now.

Thanks all!